# Microsoft Graph Beta Create call Calls.Initiate.All permission not found

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Trying to create a Teams call using the Graph API, but the `Calls.Initiate.All` is required.
In the Graph explorer I see no means to grant application permissions as delegated permissions are not supported. Is there a way to grant this permission in the explorer or must this be done programmatically? If so how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Calls.Initiate.All` is needed for `POST /app/calls` method, not `Get` method.

Since [Create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) only supports Application rather than Delegated permission and this permission is not listed in Microsoft Graph Explorer, you can choose to use Postman or Restlet or other 3rd-party to test it by [configuring Application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis) in [app registered in Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).

You could grant admin-consent on Azure portal.
[image: grant permission]

And then you could use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the access token.
[image: get token]

You could use this token to Create call.

Comment: I've created my Application, now my next step should be to (use the admin consent endpoint)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint]? The API permissions table list this for the calls API `Calls.Initiate.All Application  Not granted for Microsoft`

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=d3e66821-c835-4bfe-9b81-79b6c8db9cb2
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=
https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalls.initiate.all
&state=12345` Trying this call syntax, but getting this error `Message: AADSTS650053: The application 'Graph Test' asked for scope 'calls.initiate.all' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor`

Comment: You could use client credentials flow to get access token. See my screenshots added in the answer.